# In Libreoffice Calc, which formula will check if a a keyword or part of it is contained in a cell in a row and copy the entire content of that cell?

Tags: if-statement, search, formula, libreoffice-calc

I am learning how to use formulas in spreadsheets, I do use libre office.

I need to sort out data in a quite huge messy spreadsheet.

Each column contains mixed data, the sheet is huge, dozens of columns and thousands of rows, if the spreadsheet does not contain errors each cell in a row either contains a different keyword or is empty, there should not be two cells in the same row containing the same keyword.

The problem to solve is to sort out all the data so to reach to have a new spreadsheet in which each cell marked with a given specific keyword is kept in the same position but placed in one column dedicated to that same keyword.

*the kind of spreadsheet with mixed up cells to be sorted out*

[image: the kind of spreadsheet with mixed up cells to be sorted out]

*the data in the spreadsheet has to be fixed so to appear in this way*

[image: the data in the spreadsheet has to be fixed so to appear in this way]

A formula that can be used to extract sorted out data from a cell is the following:

`=IF(SEARCH("Text1";B2;1);B2;0)`

The formula can be dragged to each cell below to hit the proper cell next to it. The result is correct.

*The results are correct, but I do not know why the expected 0 is not printed, there is **#VALUE!** instead*

[image: The results are correct, but I do not know why the expected 0 is not printed, there is #VALUE! instead]

The logic is very simple, if the cell contains the keyword or any other text that contains that keyword the result is the full content of that cell, otherwise the result is 0.

Here comes the first question, why do I get #VALUE! as a result for those cells that do not contain the keyword? I expected to get 0 instead, just as indicated in the formula,
I tried to leave this filed empty and also to put the 0 result in quotes, the actual result is always the same, #VALUE!...

However, of course this formula extracts only the information contained in one column, so for each other column the process must be repeated.

In order to avoid to create a column with the formula for each column in the spreadsheet or anyway to process each column one by one and more importantly to have then to merge all the results to form one columns containing only cells with a given keyword I thought to use the same formula extending the parsing to each next cell in the row as follows:

`=IF(SEARCH("text";B2;1);B2;IF(SEARCH("text";C2;1);C2;IF(SEARCH("text";D2;1);D2;0)))`

The logic is very simple and should output in one go a column containing all the cells containing the keyword that are found in the row, check if the first cell in the row contains a word using the search function, if does then the result is the content of that cell, otherwise perform the next test, the next test is the same, check if the next cell contains a certain word using the search function, if does then the result is the content of that cell, otherwise proceed to the next test…. and so on until last test, if no test gave a true result then print 0 (but we get #VALUE!, OK I could live with that...).

In theory should work for a any number of cells, but in the practice does not at all, in fact does work only for the first IF test and cell indicated in the formula.

WHY?

*The result using the extended version of the formula to parse N cells in sequence is the same obtained with the simple formula to parse only one cell*

[image: The result using the extended version of the formula to parse N cells in sequence is the same obtained with the simple formula to parse only one cell]

Finally, how do I resolve this problem using IF and Search?

Is there any other better approach and way to solve this kind of problems and sort out data in huge spreadsheets of this kind?

Thank you for any hint and help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In principle, your task has several solutions - cleaning up "dirty data" can be done in a reasonable time, but this time will not be small, given the large amount of data to be processed. And yes, you can use formulas for this task. But your description of the problem is not enough to understand. How many times should the value of the cell "Car 8 text 234 shoes" be repeated (if it occurs)? Do you have a complete list of keywords that need to be sorted into different columns?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question "why do I get #VALUE! as a result" in the [**SEARCH() function Help**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3151005): ***If the text is not found, returns error 519 (#VALUE)*** Calc is strict about errors inside complex formulas - if any part of the formula contains an error, then the result of the entire formula will be an error

Comment: What you actually need is not `IF(SEARCH(...))` but something like `=IFERROR(INDEX($B3:$D3;0;MATCH("*"&G$2&"*";$B3:$D3;0));"")` - what it is and how it works, I will explain in the answer after you answer the clarifying questions.

Comment: Each cell do contain a keyword and a value, the value can vary a lot, e.g. can be just text data, "car blue", text and number "car blue 34", numbers "car 325", text, numbers and symbols "car @845 45° ±3% black", some combinations of keyword and values repeated a lot of times, but most of the combinations of keywords and values is very different each time and repeated a few times, each combination is valuable data and should be kept in the proper row, so only moved in the proper column. Yes it is possible to create the full list of keywords

Comment: Hi John, I checked the IFERROR approach you do suggest, it works pretty fine, it is a much better and viable solution for this case. To use this formula one need to create a full list of keywords, that done one can change the keyword in the G2 cell and can get from the cell's range in the row the first cell that do contain a certain keyword, thus get the copy of the full content of that cell. As in this case scenario there is only one cell with a given keyword in a given row this formula is sufficient to solve the problem. I now try it on the real huge sheet and will report about. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just one clarification: you need not only cell `G2`, but a whole range, a row with keywords. Treat them like table column headings. Each formula below, using `MATCH()`, finds a word from the header in a row of cells with dirty data and returns the number of the found cell. The `INDEX()` function will return the contents of the cell by the found number. To make `MATCH()` find the keyword anywhere in the cell, surround it with a wildcard or regexp - "any number of characters" (check the Calc settings in the **Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Calculate** section)